Where is the mistake in my answer: $|z-i| \geq 4, \text{maximum value of: } |iz + 13 - 5i|$
Let $z$ be a complex number satisfying $|z-i| \geq 4$, find the maximum value of $|iz + 13 - 5i|$.
My answer goes like this:
$|z_1 + z_2| \leq |z_1|+ |z_2| \\
z_1 = iz, z_2 = 13 - 5i \\
|z_1 + z_2| \leq |iz| + |13 - 5i|\\
|z_1 + z_2| \leq |z| + \sqrt{194}$
From $|z-i| \leq 4$, we need to extract $|z|$
$|z-i| \leq 4 $
Also, $|z-i| \leq |z| + |i|$
Therefore, $4 = |z| + 1,  |z| =3$
Now, $|z_1 + z_2| \leq 3 + \sqrt{194}$
But the answer is 17, what would go wrong in this approach?

The given condition is $|z-i|\ge4$ but not $|z-i|\le 4$.

There is a typo. I guess you meant $|z-i|\le 4.$ The inequality does not imply that $|z|=3.$ Substitute $w=z-i$ and use the fact that for $|w|\le r$ the maximal value of $|w-b|$ is equal $r+|b|.$

Btw for this question I suggest a geometric approach instead of playing with the inequality, as you still need to verify your upper bound is achievable.

Note that $|iz+13-5i| = |z-13i-5|$. Now draw a picture of the situation.

I understood it, thank you very much. I made a typo in the sign of inequality leading to the misunderstanding.

Instead of $z_1 = iz$, use $z_1 = z - i$. Now we have a numeric bound to $|z_1|$; $|z_1| \ge 4$.
Then, $|z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2| \iff |z - i + z_2| \le |z - i| + |z_2|$.
Since, $|z - i + z_2| = |iz + 13 - 5i| = |i(z - 5 - 13i)| = |i| \cdot|z - 5 - 13i| = |z - i - (5 + 12i)|$, we must have $z_2 = -(5 + 12i) \implies |z_2| = 13$.
$\therefore |iz + 13 - 5i| \le |z_1| + 13 = 4 + 13 = 17$
